# Sorting GraphQL query on multiple queries in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm using Gatsby as my static generator and Contentful as my datasource.

We've got multiple contentTypes in Contentful (blog, event, whitepaper) and I want to return these in within one query and sorted by createdAt date. So far I have the following which returns each contentType in order of each contentType but not in order of date overall.

Is there a way I can do a sort across the entire query?

```
{
    whitepapers: allContentfulWhitepaper(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
        }
      }
    }
    blogs: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
        }
      }
    }
    events: allContentfulEventPage(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think GraphQL query is able to do the sorting across multiple fields, but you can sort in component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { whitepapers, blogs, events } = data;
  const allDataInDesc = [
    ...whitepagers.edges.map(e => e.node),
    ...blogs.edges.map(e => e.node),
    ...events.edges.map(e => e.node),
  ].sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a.createdAt) > new Date(b.createdAt) ? -1 : 1; });

  return <>...</>
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    whitepapers: allContentfulWhitepaper(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
    blogs: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
    events: allContentfulEventPage(sort: { order: DESC, fields: createdAt }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can sort by multiple fields. Just pass fields and sort order as an array to your query:

```
query MyQuery {
    allContentfulPost(
        sort: { fields: [featured, updatedAt], order: [ASC, DESC] }) {
        edges {
            node {
               featured
               updatedAt(formatString: "d MM yyyy")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you so much!